# Conditionalized WHERE case with some NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, where-clause

The simplified code below does not return the rows with NULL in field1 (same issue with field2, field3). I can change anything AFTER the equals sign and could change the equals sign if need be but everything up to `WHERE field1` should remain the same.

How do I also pull the `is null` rows in this same case? The actual query is big and already in three `begin..end` blocks so I REALLY don't want to complicate it further by multiplying the 3 blocks into more. For (ALL) I want all rows and for (x) I want that particular value plus nulls and data would be equal to whatever is in the variable.

```
declare @var1 varchar(100)
declare @var2 varchar(100)
declare @var3 varchar(100)

set @var1 = '(ALL)'
set @var2 = '(x)'
set @var3 = 'data'

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
    field1 = CASE @var1 WHEN '(ALL)' THEN field1 
                        WHEN '(x)' THEN (x & nulls) 
                        ELSE @var1 
             END 
    AND field2 = CASE @var2 WHEN '(ALL)' THEN field2 
                            WHEN '(x)' THEN (x & nulls) 
                            ELSE @var2 
                 END 
    AND field3 = CASE @var3 WHEN '(ALL)' THEN field3 
                            WHEN '(x)' THEN (x & nulls) 
                            ELSE @var3 
                 END
```

I really need to case the whole WHERE line, is there no way to do that?

```
WHERE CASE @var1 WHEN '(x)' THEN field1 = @var1 or field1 is null
```

EDIT: I developed a working solution! The problem was the WHERE clause needs an assignment, it can't just be a direct CASE, so we'll implement a pseudo true/false assignment. Use similar code for @var2/field2 and @var3/field3. Hope this solution helps others in the future. Thank you all for this great website!

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
1 = CASE WHEN @var1 = '(ALL)' THEN 1
         WHEN @var1 = '(x)' AND (field1 = @var1 OR field1 IS NULL) THEN 1
         WHEN @var1 = field1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END
```

Edit: If you really want to condense it: (the field1 = @var1 is taken care of by the last WHEN condition)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
1 = CASE WHEN @var1 = '(ALL)' THEN 1
         WHEN @var1 = '(x)' AND field1 IS NULL THEN 1
         WHEN @var1 = field1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: this is for SQL Server, TSQL, so you know, null does not equal null here, hence, the problem.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you want to add NULLs to a value? I can hardly think for any application for that. If you just want to sum some values in this field which might have NULL value, use `COALESCE(field, 0)` clause.

Comment: I do not want to do any calculations. I want to display the rows with data and the rows with null. I changed the plus to ampersand to eliminate confusion.

Comment: How can I change the WHERE clause to make this work? Please note that there are other ANDs in the where clause in the actual query. Would negating it with subselects work?

Comment: I tried this but it only gave me the (x) rows, still missing the NULL. SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE field1 not in (select distinct field1 from table where field1 <> '(x)')

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your WHERE clause to something like this:

```
WHERE
    (@var1 in ('(ALL)','(x)') OR field1 = @var1)
AND (@var2 in ('(ALL)','(x)') OR field2 = @var2)
AND (@var3 in ('(ALL)','(x)') OR field3 = @var3)
```

Comment: This is giving me all the rows when @var1 = '(x)'. I should only be seeing the rows with (x) and NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answers and comments you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
(@var1 = '(ALL)' OR (@var1 ='(x)' AND IsNull(field1, '(x)') = @var1) OR field1 = @var1)
AND (@var2 = '(ALL)' OR (@var2 ='(x)' AND IsNull(field2, '(x)') = @var2) OR field2 = @var2)
AND (@var3 = '(ALL)' OR (@var3 ='(x)' AND IsNull(field3, '(x)') = @var3) OR field3 = @var3)
AND ...
```

In the event that the given 'x' can be any character sequence you are going to need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
(@var1 = '(ALL)' OR (@var1 like '(%)' AND IsNull(field1, SUBSTRING(@var1,2,LEN(@var1)-2)) = SUBSTRING(@var1,2,LEN(@var1)-2)) OR field1 = @var1)
AND (@var2 = '(ALL)' OR (@var2 like '(%)' AND IsNull(field2, SUBSTRING(@var2,2,LEN(@var2)-2)) = SUBSTRING(@var2,2,LEN(@var2)-2)) OR field2 = @var2)
AND (@var3 = '(ALL)' OR (@var3 like '(%)' AND IsNull(field3,SUBSTRING(@var3,2,LEN(@var3)-2)) = SUBSTRING(@var3,2,LEN(@var3)-2)) OR field3 = @var3)
```

To conclude my second answer I would suggest extending the complete code for some more readability:

```
declare @var1 varchar(100)
declare @var2 varchar(100)
declare @var3 varchar(100)

set @var1 = '(ALL)'
set @var2 = '(x)'
set @var3 = 'data'

declare @var1Inner varchar(100)
declare @var2Inner varchar(100)
declare @var3Inner varchar(100)

declare @var1withNull bit
declare @var2withNull bit
declare @var3withNull bit

SELECT @var1withNull = 0, @var2withNull = 0, @var3withNull = 0
IF (@var1 like '(%)') BEGIN
    SELECT @var1withNull = 1, @var1Inner = SUBSTRING(@var1,2,LEN(@var1)-2)
END
IF (@var2 like '(%)') BEGIN
    SELECT @var2withNull = 1, @var2Inner =  SUBSTRING(@var1,2,LEN(@var1)-2)
END
IF (@var3 like '(%)') BEGIN
    SELECT @var3withNull = 1, @var3Inner = SUBSTRING(@var3,2,LEN(@var3)-2)
END

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE (@var1 = '(ALL)' OR (@var1withNull = 1 AND IsNull(field1,@var1withNull) = @var1withNull) OR field1 = @var1)
AND (@var2 = '(ALL)' OR (@var2withNull = 1 AND IsNull(field2,@var2withNull) = @var2withNull) OR field2 = @var2)
AND (@var3 = '(ALL)' OR (@var3withNull = 1 AND IsNull(field3,@var3withNull) = @var3withNull) OR field3 = @var3)
```